# Visual Studio 2013 link error \.obj not found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, cmake

I am building a project with `cmake[v3.4.0]`, in `msvc2013`.

With fresh installation I am getting error like below:

```
Error 1 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'E:\Work\dev\DesktopMSVC13_Proj\src\Kernel\Network\Network.dir\Debug\.obj'  E:\Work\dev\DesktopMSVC13_Proj\src\Kernel\LINK Kernel
```

There is no issues while `cmake` makes the project. Reinstallation of `cmake` does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using `cmake[v3.2.3]` solved the issue. `cmake[v3.4.0]` cannot process a command:

```
add_library(Kernel SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:Network>
```